# Widget alignment in kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, layout, widget, kivy

i'm new in kivy and python and i would like to knkow what's wrong in my code.
I want to align a Label widget and a TextInput widget in a same layout. In other words, the two widgets have to start from the same x coordinate! In my example, i set the same x coordinate in pos_hint('center_x':0.5), but the widgets aren't align. I tried with other layout type before, but i didn't solve this issue.
any suggestion?

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class MyWidget(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(*args)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Hello", size_hint=(None, None), pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}))
        self.add_widget(TextInput(text="MyText", multiline=False, size_hint=(0.1,0.05), pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.4}))


class ex(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ex().run()
```

Comment: You want them to be next to each other?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want If I'm right about what you mean.

```
self.add_widget(Label(text="Hello", size_hint=(None, None), pos_hint={'center_x':0.4, 'center_y':0.5}))
self.add_widget(TextInput(text="MyText", multiline=False, size_hint=(0.1,0.05), pos_hint={'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.5}))
```

I think you misunderstood the pos_hint. `center_x: 0.5` means the middle of x so `center_x: 0.4` means one level to the left.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i mean something different. I want to align, in this case, the first letter of the label "H" with the beginning border of TextInput widget. The two widgets have the same coordinate, but the text of the label seems to be "centered"!